# Flutter - Firebase deploy not updating new version

Tags: firebase, flutter, web

I have done:

'''

```
    1. flutter build web
    
    2. firebase deploy
```

'''

it is not updating the new version. I have already tried flutter clean but still nothing.

Comment: did you increment the version number in pubspec.yaml and deploy ?

Comment: @epynic I have not tried that.  I just change the version: 1.0.0+1 to 1.0.0+2?

Comment: just changed it. re did the steps but still nothing

Comment: is this updated in your local ? try clean build again and push ,, try the url incognito browser.

Comment: I tried but nothing yet.  It is showing up when I debug but not when i deploy

Comment: @user2827326 did u find a solution?